# Where can I find a tutorial to get started learning jQuery?

Tags: jquery

Where is a good place to get started learning how to use jQuery?  It seems to be all the rage nowadays.  I know some basics of JavaScript but I'm by no means an expert.

Comment: http://robinz.in/begin-with-jquery/

Comment: you will find lot of examples at https://www.tutorialkart.com/jquery/ and you can get hands on experience with their try jQuery online https://www.tutorialkart.com/try-jquery-online.php

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Officially from jQuery
http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials

Or try anything on this site that compiles a bunch of jQuery learning material:

http://www.noupe.com/tutorial/51-best-of-jquery-tutorials-and-examples.html

Answer (score 12):

I can whole-heartedly recommend Manning's ['JQuery In Action'](http://www.manning.com/bibeault/).  VERY readable, and does a great job of explaining the framework-specific abstractions.

Answer (score 4):

Here's a 4 part (so far) series on [Jquery Basics](http://dotnetslackers.com/Community/blogs/xun/archive/2008/09/13/jquery-the-very-very-basics-lesson-1.aspx).

Comment: It's more than 4 parts now, and it was an extremely useful introduction series.  Thanks for the great suggestion.

Answer (score 3):

[JQuery](http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials) web site has some nice tutorials itself.

Answer (score 3):

As well as the jQuery in Action book that's already been mentioned, there's [Learning jQuery](http://www.packtpub.com/jQuery/book) and [jQuery Reference Guide](http://www.packtpub.com/jquery-reference-guide-Open-Source/book) from Packt. They work well as a pair: the Learning book has plenty of examples that they walk through in some detail - once you know what's possible, the Reference Guide helps you find the right method from the fairly comprehensive options available.

Answer (score 3):

If you're into video tutorials, check out the [jQuery for Absolute Beginners Series](http://blog.themeforest.net/tutorials/jquery-for-absolute-beginners-video-series/). It really helped to make jQuery click with me, more than traditional tutorials.

Answer (score 2):

Have you looked through [jQuery.com](http://docs.jquery.com/)? Their documentation is really excellent.

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot of them out there, google it, and the jQuery official site itself has a huge list of tutorials and excellent documentation with working examples. If that's not enough, try http://jqueryfordesigner.com, http://bassistance.de. I have also written some at my blog, http://www.chazzuka.com/blog.

Answer (score 1):

I ran across a [site with JQuery videos](http://www.mefeedia.com/tags/jquery/) recently.

There was also a [Hanselminutes podcast on the subject of jQuery](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/HanselminutesPodcast126ChatWithJohnResigCreatorOfJQuery.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

I've found the links from "[The Complete jQuery Resource List for You to Become an Almighty Developer](http://effectize.com/jquery-developer-guide)" to be very helpful.

Comment: February 2010 the link no longer works. If anybody knows a new one, please edit the answer to add it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There are lots of articles on JQuery on the web. Here's one for a beginner:

http://www.dotnetcube.com/post/Getting-started-with-JQuery-in-ASPNET.aspx

Answer (score 1):

I started with [15 days of jquery](http://15daysofjquery.com/)

Answer (score 1):

I've just run into this one. I recommend it because it explains the basics and gives a solid foundation that you can build on.

http://blog.mikecouturier.com/2010/02/beginning-with-jquery-solid-foundation_22.html