# What are the best references for using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, reference

I'm interested in what you find are the best development references for learning and using jQuery. Books, websites, etc. are all welcome.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[jQuery in Action](http://www.manning.com/bibeault/), FTW

Comment: I was actually pondering purchasing that book, and appreciate the input!

Answer (score 4):

I've found both the [official documentation](http://docs.jquery.com/Main_Page) and the [VisualJQuery](http://visualjquery.com/) references are very solid.

Answer (score 4):

See [Where can I find a tutorial to get started learning jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/168802/where-can-i-find-a-tutorial-to-get-started-learning-jquery#168810)

Answer (score 3):

The best reference is by far [jQuery Documentation Page](http://docs.jquery.com/Main_Page) itself :)

Answer (score 3):

Rick Strahl's [jQuery Articles](http://www.west-wind.com/Weblog/ShowPosts.aspx?Category=jQuery)
Dave Ward's [Articles on jQuery](http://encosia.com/category/jquery/)
Check out [.Net Answers blog](http://blog.dmbcllc.com/tag/jquery/) too