# Forcing BigDecimals to use scientific notation

Tags: java, bigdecimal

I have this method:

```
    public void Example(BigDecimal value, int scale){
    BigDecimal x = new BigDecimal("0.00001");
    System.out.println("result: " + (value.multiply(x)).setScale(scale, RoudingMode.HALF_UP).toString());
```

If, per example, value = 1 and scale = 2, the output is "result: 0.00". I thought it would be 1.00E-5. So, my doubt is: How can I force a BigDecimal to be formated in scientific notation if its scale is bigger than a certain value (it was 2 in my example) ?

Comment: Why not to use its own `toString` or `toEngineeringString`methods?

Comment: @PM77-1: Neither *always* uses scientific notation. And engineering notation is *not always* scientific notation.

Comment: @PM because, for what I'm doing, I need it to be _scientific_ notation, not Engineering...

Comment: This might not be very helpful, but here's a way to print `1.0E-5`: `x.doubleValue()`

Comment: You could use basic math to figure out. `(num / pow(10, floor(log(num))) + "E" + floor(log(num))`.

Comment: I often wish there was a toScientificString() method when debugging. It bugs me that there isn't.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use a [`DecimalFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html) with `setMinimumFractionDigits(int scale)`:

```
private static String format(BigDecimal x, int scale) {
  NumberFormat formatter = new DecimalFormat("0.0E0");
  formatter.setRoundingMode(RoundingMode.HALF_UP);
  formatter.setMinimumFractionDigits(scale);
  return formatter.format(x);
}
...
System.out.println(format(new BigDecimal("0.00001"), 2)); // 1.00E-5
System.out.println(format(new BigDecimal("0.00001"), 3)); // 1.000E-5
```

Comment: But what if the value of the scale changes? How can I handle that?

Comment: See below for a version of this that automatically sets the scale.

Comment: Note: DecimalFormat only handles numbers that can be expressed as Doubles. Try formatting BigDecimal("1e400"), it gives you "∞".

Answer (score 11):

Here is a version of DannyMo's answer that sets the scale automatically:

```
private static String format(BigDecimal x)
{
    NumberFormat formatter = new DecimalFormat("0.0E0");
    formatter.setRoundingMode(RoundingMode.HALF_UP);
    formatter.setMinimumFractionDigits((x.scale() > 0) ? x.precision() : x.scale());
    return formatter.format(x);
}

System.out.println(format(new BigDecimal("0.01")));   // 1.0E-2
System.out.println(format(new BigDecimal("0.001")));  // 1.0E-3
System.out.println(format(new BigDecimal("500")));    // 5E2
System.out.println(format(new BigDecimal("500.05"))); // 5.00050E2
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use something like this:

```
int maxScale = 2;

BigDecimal value = BigDecimal.ONE;
BigDecimal x = new BigDecimal("0.00001");
BigDecimal result = value.multiply(x);

if (result.scale() > maxScale) {
    System.out.format("result: %.2E\n", result); // You can change .2 to the value you need
} else {
    System.out.println("result: " + result.toPlainString());
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try the **`DecimalFormat`** class. It has format methods for methods for double and long numbers so you should do something like this:

```
BigDecimal x = new BigDecimal("0.00001");
DecimalFormat frmt = new DecimalFormat("0.00E00");
String formatted = frmt.format(x.doubleValue());
System.out.println("result: " + formatted);
```

[DecimalFormat javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html)

Comment: Moving a big decimal to double can mess up the value. This is not a solution.