# Engineering representation of a BigDecimal instance

Tags: java, javafx, bigdecimal

How can I configure a `BigDecimal` value so that if it has less that 32 characters, it should be displayed as a plain String, and otherwise it should be represented in an engeneering format?

For instance:

> 3690215840369.69874120035964120  - plain string
>   369043523215840369.69874120035964120  - engineering format of representation

I've tried to resolve this in the following way:

```
    BigDecimal bd = new BigDecimal("8678679532108467840356746356832624562456786656736.6456442652456345673656");
    System.out.println(bd.toEngineeringString());
    System.out.println(bd.toPlainString());
```

But the outputs are the same. So, how can I gain engineering representation of a `BigDecimal` instance?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Forcing BigDecimals to use scientific notation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18027047/forcing-bigdecimals-to-use-scientific-notation)

Answer (score 1):

Couldn't you do something like this:

```
BigDecimal bd = new BigDecimal("8678679532108467840356746356832624562456786656736.6456442652456345673656");
System.out.println(bd.toPlainString().length()<32 ? bd.toPlainString() : bd.toEngineeringString());
```

and if you need to ignore the decimal point when checking for 32:

```
BigDecimal bd = new BigDecimal("8678679532108467840356746356832624562456786656736.6456442652456345673656");
int decimalOffset = 0;
if (bd.toPlainString().indexOf('.')>=0)
        decimalOffset=1;
System.out.println(bd.toPlainString().length()-decimalOffset<32 ? bd.toPlainString() : bd.toEngineeringString());
```

but if you're meaning *scientific* notation, then go check out Steve's answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25794946/5128011) and combine that with the first part of my answer by replacing `bd.toEngineeringString()` with `format(bd)`