# Learn jQuery websites

Tags: asp.net, jquery, visual-studio

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Where can I find a tutorial to get started learning jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/168802/where-can-i-find-a-tutorial-to-get-started-learning-jquery)

I am very interested in learning jQuery.  Is there any website that could aid me in learning jQuery? Any good book recommendations would be great too. I love JavaScript and use it often but jQuery is a different beast in itself.

Comment: How is thsi a community wiki-worthy question? It's not.

Comment: duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/168802/where-can-i-find-a-tutorial-to-get-started-learning-jquery

Comment: had that duplicate shown up after I entered in my subject maybe i would have read it! –

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this site: http://www.noupe.com/tutorial/51-best-of-jquery-tutorials-and-examples.html.

You can also print out this cheat sheet: http://www.javascripttoolbox.com/jquery/cheatsheet/JQueryCheatSheet-1.3.2.pdf.

Comment: no problem :) it's awesome... it really helped me get a handle on jquery.

Answer (score 2):

http://visualjquery.com/ is a great guide for when your working with JQuery.

Answer (score 1):

I have the [jQuery In Action](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1933988355) book, and it is a very good reference for jQuery.

[http://www.amazon.com/jQuery-Action-Bear-Bibeault/dp/1933988355](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1933988355)

Answer (score 1):

http://jqueryfordesigners.com/

Answer (score 0):

I often visit [Learningjquery.com](http://www.learningjquery.com/), and it might sound weird, but I learned more of jQuery in the small time that I used this site than in the half year before that.
I read almost 75% of the jQuery related questions here. And you learn quite a few new tricks, and best practices  when you do that.

Answer (score 0):

[Glimmer](http://a.noma.li/8), released by Microsoft is quite nice. you can learn more about it [here.](http://a.noma.li/9)

Answer (score 0):

This is the best link I have come across, "JQuery Secrets with Dave Ward":

http://polymorphicpodcast.com/shows/jquery/