# What is the best way to begin with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Where can I find a tutorial to get started learning jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/168802/where-can-i-find-a-tutorial-to-get-started-learning-jquery)

Considering I am new to jQuery technology, what is the best way to begin with it?

Comment: Related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/168802/where-can-i-find-a-tutorial-to-get-started-learning-jquery

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first step might be to take a look at its [documentation](http://docs.jquery.com/Main_Page) : it will allow you see what it can do, and the basics of the "how".

Answer (score 5):

Visiting http://jquery.com/ and [reading the tutorials](http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials) is probably the best way to go.  Google works really well too.

Comment: Don't forget Visual jQuery (http://visualjquery.com/)! (even if it hasn't been updated)

Answer (score 3):

When I first started I opened up notepad and put the following code in

```
<html>
    <head>                                                                  
        <script src="http://ajax.microsoft.com/ajax/jquery/jquery-1.3.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>          
        <script type="text/javascript">                                         
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $("a").click(function() {
                        alert("Hello world!");
                    });
            });

        </script>                                                               
    </head>                                                                 
<body>                                                                  
   <a href="#" id="Test"></a>                                     
</body>                                                                 
</html>
```

After I got that working I visted Jquery.com and 1 by one tried each of the JQuery API reference sections and tried a few of them out. You can find those here http://docs.jquery.com/Main_Page

They have quite a lot of tutorials, however, I personally found it easier to just try things out for myself using the API reference. I also found cheat sheets like this one useful: http://net.tutsplus.com/freebies/cheat-sheets/jquery-cheat-sheet/

I then read these excelent tips:
http://www.tvidesign.co.uk/blog/improve-your-jquery-25-excellent-tips.aspx

Then learn't to put a plugin together here:
http://www.learningjquery.com/2007/10/a-plugin-development-pattern

Thats it really... In a nutshell that's how I learn't JQuery.

Answer (score 1):

If you are new to jQuery, you'd best go to the [jQuery](http://jquery.com) website, and then read some [jQuery tutorials](http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials).

And of course practice: just try it, jQuery is not very hard to learn, so just try to implement it in a website, and refer to the jQuery website or to SO to get help.

Answer (score 0):

I would start with the JQuery Tutorial straight from the JQuery site

- http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials

Answer (score 0):

[How jQuery Works](http://docs.jquery.com/How_jQuery_Works)

[jQuery Tutorials](http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials)

Answer (score 0):

The docs are a great place to start.  They have good examples of different functionality.
[jQuery Docs](http://docs.jquery.com/Main_Page)

Answer (score 0):

Some suggestions:
 - Try a few development environments and tools (IntelliJ, Firebug)
 - Write a todo application [that beats mine](http://todo.seasidehosting.st) :)