# Loking for some good and simple jquery tutorials

Tags: jquery

I want something that's simple, in-depth and explains from basics.

Comment: As there can be no one "right" answer to this, would you edit your question and tick the "community wiki" box?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Where can I find a tutorial to get started learning jQuery?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/168802/where-can-i-find-a-tutorial-to-get-started-learning-jquery), [Jquery video tutorial resources](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/401810/jquery-video-tutorial-resources), and many more related questions. Also a simple search request on your favorite engine would give you a pretty good list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a [listing of jQuery tutorials](http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials) on the jQuery website. "How jQuery Works" and "Getting Started with jQuery" might be good places to start.

Answer (score 1):

**[W3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/default.asp)** will be one of the good choice.

Answer (score 1):

[docs.jquery.com/Tutorials](http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials)

And some more links to great tutorials

- [jQuery Tutorials for Designers](http://www.webdesignerwall.com/tutorials/jquery-tutorials-for-designers/)
- [51+ Best of jQuery Tutorials and Examples](http://www.noupe.com/tutorial/51-best-of-jquery-tutorials-and-examples.html)

Answer (score 0):

http://www.learningjquery.com/2010/07/great-ways-to-learn-jquery#more-1164

Answer (score 0):

http://tutsplus.com/course/30-days-to-learn-jquery/
I found these video tutorials good to get you off to a start. Requires that you know a little javascript but will cover the basics to start with and then gets more involved after the 10th instalment or so. But as with anything, nothing beats just getting your hands dirty and implement jquery with your projects.